# display current data from localstorage

Tags: angular, typescript

i'm trying to display current data from localstorage. i can see data in the localstoarge but it not displayed.on page, data will display when i refresh the page.
i want to display the data without refreshing page.

**service.ts**

```ts
    constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
      this.userData = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user'));
  
      }

       public get userStorageData() { 
          return this.userData;
       }
  


    registerUser(data){
      return this.http.post(`${environment.API_ENDPOINT}/users`,data, {observe: 'response'})
      .pipe(map(user => {
      localStorage.setItem('user', JSON.stringify(user.body));
      return user;
     }));
    }
```

**firstComponent.ts**

```ts
      onSubmit() { 
       const data = this.registrationForm.value;
       this.userService.registerUser(data).subscribe((response)=>{
      this.registrationData = response;
      if(this.registrationData.status === 201){
        const message = 'Registration successfull!';
        alert(message);
        this.router.navigate([`/secondComponent`]);
      }
     
    })
  }
```

In this component I want to display data

**secondcomponent.ts**

```ts
       this.user = this.userService.userStorageData;
```

**secondcomponent.html**

```html
     <div class="container">
       <table class="table table-striped">
         <thead>
           <tr>
             <th style="width: 20%">First Name</th>
             <th style="width: 20%">Last Name</th>
             <th style="width: 20%">Email</th>
             <th style="width: 20%">Phone</th>
           </tr>
         </thead>
        <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>{{user.firstName}}</td>
          <td>{{user.lastName}}</td>
          <td>{{user.email}}</td>
          <td>{{user.phone}}</td>  
        </tr>
       </tbody>
      </table>
     </div>
```

Comment: Where did you place the `this.user = this.userService.userStorageData;` logic in the `secondcomponent`?

Comment: @MaartenDev in the constructor.

Comment: Could you try placing it inside the `ngOnInit` method? More details can be found here: https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks#oninit

Comment: I think you need to set `this.userData` in the service within the observer function in `registerUser`, which should trigger change detection in the component using that value. Like this: `this.userData = user.body`

Comment: @MaartenDev yes i tried but not work.

Comment: can you just move this.userData = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user'));  logic in service file from constructor to a separate function
  public  getUserStorageData() { 
          return this.userData;
       } then subscribe  with this.userService.getUserStorageData().subscribe(data => {console.log(data)};